# Solution added to the answer: Web Scraping Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Web Scraping Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, https

There are two python files.

The file titled `munilist.py` looks as follows (with around 7000+ municipality name-URL pairs):

```
munilist = ('porto-empedocle', 'https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/porto-empedocle-comune-ag/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo'), ('comitini', 'https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/comitini-comune-ag/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo'), ('montevago', 'https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/montevago-comune-ag/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo')]
```

Now, the file `italy.py` (in the same directory) is as follows:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os

from munilist import muni

os.chdir(r"/Users/aartimalik/Dropbox/data/italy")


for label, URL in muni:
    r = requests.get(URL)
    p = re.compile("var bilancio_tree = (.*?);")
    data = p.search(r.text).group(1)

    data = json.loads(data)

    all_data = []

    for d in data:
        for v in d["values"]:
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                all_data.append([d["label"], "-", kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")])
            
        for c in d["children"]:
            for v in c["values"]:
                for kk, vv in v.items():
                    all_data.append([d["label"], c["label"], kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")])
                    
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["label 1", "label 2", "year", "abs", "PC"])

    df.to_csv(label+"-data.csv", index=False)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Could someone please help me understand how to figure this out?

Referring to this URL (openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/comitini-comune-ag/entrate/…); we can see var bilancio_tree =  but it looks like the first URL is not working at all. Is there a way to tell python to ignore such cases?

**Solution:**

Using try-except worked!

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os

from munilist import muni

os.chdir(r"/Users/aartimalik/Dropbox/delphine-miscellaneous/italy")

for label, URL in muni:

    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        p = re.compile("var bilancio_tree = (.*?);")
        data = p.search(r.text).group(1)

        data = json.loads(data)

        all_data = []
        
        for d in data:
            for v in d["values"]:
                for kk, vv in v.items():
                    all_data.append([d["label"], "-", kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")])
                
            for c in d["children"]:
                for v in c["values"]:
                    for kk, vv in v.items():
                        all_data.append(
                            [d["label"], c["label"], kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")]
                            )
                        
        df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["label 1", "label 2", "year", "abs", "pc"])
    
        df.to_csv(label+"-data.csv", index=False)

    except:
        print("did not work")
```

Comment: What are you trying to search with [tag:regex]? There is `bilancio` on the response text, but there is neither `var ` not `_tree` there, that's why you're getting this error on trying to access a group that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Referring to this URL (https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/comitini-comune-ag/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo); we can see `var bilancio_tree = `  but it looks like the first URL is not working at all. Is there a way to tell python to ignore such cases? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Using try-except did the job!

Comment: You could just use an `if` statement to test if `re.search` found anything.